# Struts 2 display image

Tags: java, image, jsp, struts2

I am looking for a simpler solution to display an image inside a JSP page, within a Struts2 application. The solution which I found so far (and is working) is this one: [Struts 2 dynamic image example](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-dynamic-image-example/).

However, writing the image as a stream of bytes seems to me like an overkill. Is there any other simpler solution? or it is absolutely necessary to use a stream of bytes?

Simply, writing `<img src="#image_location_on_disk">`is not an acceptable solution, because I want struts to be responsible for bringing my image (in my business logic I decide whether an image should be displayed or not)

Comment: If you want to stream the image for a location which is not publicly visible to the browser, then this is the standard way to do it.

Comment: If it is a static resource then just use `<img>` tag and you can use S2 `<s:if>` tag to decide whether to show image or not.

Comment: @Aleksandr M  forgot to mention - the images are rather dynamic. The situation is like this - i have a photo album, to which i can add photos/ from which i can delete photos. s:if tag is not sufficient

Comment: In that case just use `FileInputStream` to read image, assign it to the inputsream and use `stream` result for the action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If you want to stream the image for a location which is not publicly visible to the browser, then this is the standard way to do it.

---

> In that case just use `FileInputStream` to read image, assign it to the inputsream and use stream result for the action.

---

In Struts2 you can perform the task of serving image with the `stream` result instead of writing directly to the response. You can also configure this result to the corresponding content type.

Comment: but isn't stream result suitable for download, instead of displaying an image?

Comment: It could be used for both because it's writing to the response, the browser can get it and display the image.

Comment: yes, Tim Biegeleisen  told me above that it can't be done in a simpler way. but it is a comment, and I can't mark it as an accepted answer

Comment: @LPetre: It can be done simpler -> read my comment to your question.

Comment: @LPetre I put his and AleksandrM comments to my answer, so you can accept it now. Also don't forget give a credit to authors.